# Kendo UI Grid - Filter with Select Multi-Checkbox

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Problem is that when I choose multiple checkbox and filter for something all checkbox selected returns to normal all checkbox's (un-checked)

my question is : Can I do the checked some checkbox's and filter for something without do any changes on my rows checked

please check photos in below :

> 1 - [Checked some rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVxdk.png)
>
> 2 - [filter some rows where contains  'ss'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Y4j.png)
>
> 3 - [here my problem, after press ok on filter get rows without
>   checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGGoU.png)

when i'm using kendo ui v.2018 see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz3ET.png)

please help me!!
Thanks UW.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **persistSelection** property of your grid to **true**.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { selectable: true, width: "50px" },
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33},
      { id: 3, name: "Jim Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 4, name: "Jack Doe", age: 33}
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" }
    }
  },
  filterable: true,
  pageable: {
    pageSize: 2
  },
  persistSelection: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
```

Comment: @dina-diagovic Can you provide the source code of your grid? I don't understand how you're using kendo v.2016.3.914 because checkbox selection has been added in newer versions.